# Questions on documenting JavaScript: JS types

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, conventions

Considering I am going to work with a larger team in the future, I'm trying to teach myself some basic annotation and documentation principles for front-end languages. Currently I'm working on JS.

For the most part, I'm using [Google's Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) as a go-to, but I still have some questions.

Let's say I have an ajax function like so:

```
function initFunction(src, wrapper) {
  $.getJSON(src, {
    format: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    var wrapper = $(wrapper),
      contents = callAnotherFunction($(data)[0]);

    // Populates the wrapper element.
    wrapper.append(contents );

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
  });
}
```

The function has two `@param`, src and wrapper. Here are some questions.

callAnotherFunction(), then, takes as an argument an Object and it should return some HTML.

1. what's the type of src? Considering it's JSON, `{Object}`?
2. what's the type of wrapper? Considering it's a value such as `"#myId"`, String?
3. what's the return type of this function? It's a void function, but I don't know what I would call its return *type*. Does it return null?
4. what's the type of HTML that you can append to an element? Is it a `String`?
5. what is the JSDoc convention for displaying all of this? Something like this?

`/**
     * This is a description of this function. It gets a JSON file, uses it as 
     *     a jQuery object, and then call another function with the new data.
     * @param  {Object} src     JSON file to parse.
     * @param  {String} wrapper HTML element to use as a wrapper for the output.
     * @return {Null}
     */`

Comment: jsdoc can help write manuals, but i like meaningful fn/var names and Hungarian on the formal parameters; outside comments don't show up in the console or exceptions... consider how `function fetchAndInjectContent(strUrl, elmTarget)` goes a long way to answering those mental questions without seeing the parseable comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Most of my day-to-day *reading* on SO happens in a free moment on my phone. Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to award the bounty  from the app. I'll get to it as soon as I'm on a computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The type of the argument is not related to what it represents, but is the JavaScript type of the argument. In your case `src` is a string containing the url (it doesn't matter retrieving the url retrieves JSON) so the type is string.  More info [here](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html).
2. Yes, it's a string.
3. If the function doesn't have a return value just don't mention it in the JSDoc.
4. As per [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it's:

> Type: htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery
>
> DOM element, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the  end of each element in the set of matched elements.

So it depends on what you want to document your function as accepting. If you want to document it as accepting multiple types, you [use parentheses and the `|` character](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#multiple-types-and-repeatable-parameters) (example below).

5. Close, but you don't want a return type. Some people also put a blank line between the description and the params, but that's not required by the parser.

   ```
   /**
    * This is a description of this function. It gets a JSON file, uses it as 
    * a jQuery object, and then call another function with the new data.
    *
    * @param  {Object} src     JSON file to parse.
    * @param  {(String|jQuery|DOMElement)} wrapper HTML element to use as a wrapper for the output.
    */
   function initFunction(src, wrapper) {
   // ...
   ```

   In the above, we've indicated that `wrapper` can be a string, jQuery object, or DOMElement. We didn't get into the details of it possibly being an array, nor whether the string is a selector or an HTML fragment. The description would need to handle that. With a lot of choices, you may have to fall back on `{*}`.

   If the parser may not be able to tell if this is a function, you'd also add the [`@function` tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-function.html):

   ```
   /**
    * This is a description of this function. It gets a JSON file, uses it as 
    * a jQuery object, and then call another function with the new data.
    *
    * @function
    *
    * @param  {Object} src     JSON file to parse.
    * @param  {(String|jQuery|DOMElement)} wrapper HTML element to use as a wrapper for the output.
    */
   var initFunction = function(src, wrapper) {
   // ...
   ```

   Depending on context, you may prefer `@method` to `@function` (they're synonyms).

Comment: I'll reward you the bounty as soon as possible. Apparently this isn't possible from within the so app.

Comment: @BramVanroy: In [this particular case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (the bounty posted by you, the questioner; answer posted during the bounty; bounty expired; you accepted the answer), it's automatic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As Emanuele already said, the first argument can only be a string, which represents an URL.

However, the second parameter (wrapper) could be either a `string` or a `DOM element`. Not just a string.

I don't know how you could instruct JSDoc that the variable could be of two different types though.

Comment: What would be the difference between a DOM Element and a string?

Comment: a DOM Element is an {Object} which is a different type from string

Comment: that would be an instance of the class HTMLElement, you can read about it on  MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Answer (score 0):

First you should use the jQuery JSDoc [extern](http://closureplease.com/externs/) file.
Annotate the functions accordingly, the functions are annotated this way because 
of the jQuery extern file.

```
/**
* @param  {!string} src
* @param {(jQuerySelector|Element|Object|Array<Element>|jQuery|string|function())=} wrapper 
*/
function initFunction(src, wrapper) {
    $.getJSON(src, {
       format: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        var wrapper = $(wrapper),
            contents = callAnotherFunction($(data)[0]);

       // Populates the wrapper element.
       wrapper.append(contents);

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    });
}

/**
* @param {!Object} obj
* @return {(string|Element|Array<Element>|jQuery|function(number,string))}
*/
function callAnotherFunction(obj) {
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum function documentation I usual do is:

```
/**
 Purpose:  state the purpose of the function
 parameters:
  src: string, required: the url to the api service.  [paramName: type, option: purpose.
 {list individual parameters}
 Assumption: describe any dependencies. Any callback, etc.
 Return: string, json format.
*/
function foo(src, param) {}
```

Put yourself in someone's shoes.  What do you need to know quickly before attempt to make any change to someone's code.